# Spring + Maven + Intellij +HelloWorld

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've some google in the search field about my problem, but i don't get solution. In the spring project (not boot)  creating in intellij idea via maven I set up all things (see below) like tomcat configuration, java config for simple helloWorld etc... But: i got result only with exploded war and not in the welcome directory: i saw it at localhost:8080 (not at localhost:8080/welcome). 
if i set artifact as war   I get usual tomcat home page and nothing about my project.

code snpippets below:

Controller:

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("hello", "Hello");
        model.addAttribute("anyone", "anyone");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

WebApplicationContextConfig:

```
package com.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com")
public class WebAppContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

DispatcherServletInitializer:

```
package com.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebAppContextConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

 </project>
```

[Run configuration window:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZJuH.png)

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGMrK.png)

Comment: post your folder structure

Comment: Why don't you use Spring Boot? It saves you from fiddling around with the basics and just works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to bother yourself with Spring Configuration files and use Spring Boot where you have it already configured for you.

For instance, this 'hello world' sample should do what you want: https://github.com/pgrimard/spring-boot-hello-world

Also, consider http://start.spring.io/ for generating a skeleton of your project.

Comment: I have a problem not with Spring, the problem is in the deployment on Tomcat in intellij using Spring. On the STS I can do what I want. 
About spring boot - its too high level of abstraction for me and I also head that it provide embded Tomcat for every project. In the same time i can manualy configure any quantity of files on the tomcat on server(i.e. now i dont know how to manage embded TC in boot).

Comment: Well, you can configure spring-boot to provide a .war file for you if you wish. It takes two extra steps to change it - change packaging to war and add two dependencies as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: Moreover, if you use http://start.spring.io/ then you can choose 'war' packaging there (after you press 'Switch to the full version' button). The generated project can be deployed on Tomcat easily, without any problems.